# Chef-solo integration with Capistrano

Tags: capistrano, chef-infra

Is there an alternative to the [capistrano-chef](https://github.com/cramerdev/capistrano-chef) gem for chef-solo?  Mostly, to avoid defining server information twice.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found something fresh and hot on the topic:

[Roundsman](https://github.com/iain/roundsman)

Gemfile:

```
gem 'roundsman', :require => false
```

Capfile:

```
require 'roundsman/capistrano'
```

See readme for details.

Answer (score 0):

I decided to write a ruby gem to parse the files in `nodes/*.json` and transform them to Capistrano-friendly addresses:

[gem "Chef_Solo_Nodes"](https://github.com/da99/Chef_Solo_Nodes)

Then, in the cap deploy file:

```
require "Chef_Solo_Nodes"
role :app, *Chef_Solo_IPs('app')
role :db, *Chef_Solo_IPs('db')
```

Which is equivalent to:

```
role :app, "user@host:port", "xx.xx.xx.xx"
role :db, "xx.xx.xx.xx"
```

Each `node/*.json` file can optionally define attributes:

- ipaddress
- user (or login)
- port